# word2vec embedding is not utf 8 encoded - saving disabled

Tags: python, nltk, word2vec

So what I'm simply trying to do is save a Word2Vec model.

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import product_reviews_1 as review
import gensim

model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(review.sents())
model.save('review.embedding')
```

The code runs normally and there's this file review.embedding on my directory, but it has nothing but an error that says

> the file is not UTF encoded and saving is disabled

Couldn't figure out what is wrong.

Comment: Isn't it this issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61114350/error-blahfile-is-not-utf-8-encoded-saving-disabled

Comment: What do you mean that "it has nothing but an error that says `the file is not UTF encoded and saving is disabled`"? What did you use to try to view the file, and where was that text displayed? Is the file on disk just ~50 bytes, as it would be if it were just that text? Have you tried doing a `reloaded_model = Word2Vec.load('review.embedding')` & checking if that gives a working model?