# Pandas to_excel() UTF-8 Error (Saving disabled)

Tags: pandas, dataframe, utf-8, export-to-excel

I am trying to send data to an `.xlsx` file. The file is being created however in the file it is saying that `tablo_text.xlsx is not UTF-8 encoded. Saving disabled.`

The code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]
a = np.array(list)
a = a.reshape(4,4)
tablo = pd.DataFrame(a, index=["a", "b", "c", "d"], columns=["x","y","z","t"])
tablo.to_excel("tablo_text.xlsx", encoding='UTF-8')
```

Comment: Same error as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61114350/.  The linked question/answer implies you can ignore it.  FYI I ran your code and the file opens fine.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html), *encoding* is only a necessary parameter for `.xlwt` and other writers support Unicode natively.  So drop the parameter.

Comment: It is same when I drop the parameter. thank you